# Size-to-content FormItem height

Tags: apache-flex, sizing

I put a FormItem in a Form like below.

```
<mx:Form width="100%">
            <mx:FormItem label="Context Aware" width="100%" backgroundColor="red">
                <editorControls:CheckBox/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
```

There's gap between the actual content height and the form item boundary. Any idea on how to strictly fit the FormItem height to content?

This is Image:

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44679/155739

Comment: This looks like it has to do something with padding. Have you tried setting the `padding` to 0 ?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, I did try below, but it doesn't change anything. Here is the image (http://i40.tinypic.com/126b38y.png), as you see, there's gap shown in blue blocks.
`<mx:FormItem label="Context Aware" width="100%" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0" backgroundColor="red">
     <editorControls:CheckBox/>
    </mx:FormItem>`

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is actually a button with an image overlaid on it, as an icon.  The icon is a box with some whitespace, as an image.  You will have to create a new image which does not have whitespace, and replace the current icon.  Remember that this applies to downstate and so on, so you will need a series of similar images.  (cf., Adobe's [Button docs example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html#includeExamplesSummary)).

Of course, you will also have to set `verticalGap` and `indicatorGap` as well as `paddingTop` to 0, on the `CheckBox`, `FormItem`, and `Form`.  (cf., Adobe's Flex help on [Form, FormHeading, and FormItem layout containers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html#includeExamplesSummary), the section titled "Laying out forms").

Here is some sample code:

```
<mx:Form width="100%" backgroundColor="0x0000ff" verticalGap="0" paddingTop="0" indicatorGap="0">
    <mx:FormItem label="Context Aware" width="100%" backgroundColor="0x00ff00"  verticalGap="0" paddingTop="0" indicatorGap="0">
        <mx:CheckBox  verticalGap="0" paddingTop="0" icon="@Embed('cbIcon.gif')"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

(If the answer is wrong, please let me know.  If it is right, please check it as "correct".)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem remains the same.